# Jquery Datatable not working when accessing a json array by key

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to load a Jquery Datatable through an Ajax call. I have plenty of these on my site and they work no problem, however I can't seem to get this one to work properly.

I have the following set: `"sAjaxDataProp" : "data.orders[0].addresses",`. That part of the Json array has 3 elements that the table should loop over... however the table puts in 63 blank rows (and complains about the fields not being there). If I add another row to the source data, then the rows go from 63 blank rows to 79.

Any ideas what is going on here? The only think that I can think I have done differently with this one is accessing an array by key (`data.orders[0]`.addresses`).

```
 "sAjaxDataProp" : "data.orders[0].addresses",
    "aoColumns": [            
        { "data" : "name" },
        { "data" : "address1" },
        { "data" : "suburb" },
        { "data" : "state" },
        { "data" : "postcode" },
        { "data" : "country" },
        { "data" : "address_type" },
```

I am using `DataTables 1.10.4`.

My Json looks like this:

```
{"success":true,"message":"","severity":"","data":{"orders":[{"id":"34","customer_reference":null,"authority_to_leave":false,"instructions":null,"order_value":null,"create_date":"2015-01-07 08:46:34","order_date":null,"active":true,"user":{"id":"1","first_name":"xxx","last_name":"xxx","email":"xxx","username":"xxx","receive_order_confirmation_emails":false,"is_admin":true,"is_edi_user":true,"is_debug":true,"active":true},"products":[],"addresses":[{"id":"8","name":"xxx","xxx":"xxx","address2":"","suburb":"xxx","state":"xxx","postcode":"xxx6","country":"xxx","phone":"","email":"","business_name":"","business_hours":"","active":true,"address_type":"Frequent","order_address_id":"22"}],"status":[]}]}}
```

Comment: what version of plugin and what do your column definitions look like? Post more of the initialization properties object

Comment: API changed at 1.10, not sure what properties are backward compatible but after 1.10 uses more readable properties like `columns:[]`

Comment: @charlietfl- OK thanks for that- any ideas on my problem though? If I use `data.orders` (where there is only 1 element), then it only shows 1 row, but as soon as I add in the `[0]`, it jumps to 15.

Comment: never used the `"sAjaxDataProp"`. If I had non standard structure would write my own ajax callback since there is a method in API to do that. Check for new API options names , see if that helps

Comment: OK got it to work:     `"sAjaxDataProp" : function(json) { return json.data.orders[0].addresses; },`